# show API Reviews from our site to other site

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to show the reviews given on my site for a particular brand by customers to that brand's official site? I am giving one example to clear my question. Suppose any customer has given review about nike on my website( Brandact) and i want to show this review to nike's official website(through the website Brandact). 
If yes,Can someone please help me in solving this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No its not possible at your end Nike should have to integrate your API in there code

Comment: not posible. for this you need nike to adapt their code

Comment: @c.grey Sir if it's not a big brand like nike and it's a small startup brand even then it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do to make that happen on somebody else's site, short of hacking them. The people in charge of the external site have to put whatever content you want shown on their site, so you could ask them nicely.